# Android inflate(R.layout.xyz, parent, false) leads to empty rows in CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-adapter, android-inflate

I've been chasing this bug for a few hours, and now that I've finally fixed it, I don't understand what caused it in the first place. I have a custom [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html) with the following piece of code (full code posted at the end):

```java
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, parent, false);    // method 1
    // ...
}
```

The result:

[image: empty rows]

Turning on "Show layout bounds" in developer options and inspecting the layout via the Hierarchy Viewer both reveal that the rows are completely empty (no child views). Stepping through the code reveals that `newView()` and `bindView()` are called appropriately, layout inflation happens correctly (apparently), and data is correctly retrieved from the cursor and bound to the views in each row. Also the rows and their child views have their visibility flags set to `VISIBLE` and have non-zero dimensions. This leads me to conclude that my row layouts are not getting attached to the `ListView`, somehow.

It starts working as soon as I change it to:

```java
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, null);    // method 2
    // ...
}
```

This naturally prompted me to read the documentation on [`LayoutInflater.inflate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) more thoroughly. As far as I understand, the first method should've worked just fine. And in fact method 2 should *not* be used because [it causes the parent's `LayoutParams` to be completely ignored](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/).

So my question is simply this: why doesn't method 1 work when it's supposed to be The Right Way™? Is it because there's something *else* wrong with my code (see below)?

```java
private class XYZAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;

    public XYZAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int flags) {
        super(context, cursor, flags);
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.xyz, parent, false);

        view.setTag(R.id.abc, view.findViewById(R.id.abc));
        // ... similarly cache references to all child views,
        // to avoid excessive calls to findViewById()

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        TextView abc = (TextView) view.getTag(R.id.abc);
        // ... extract all cached child view references

        abc.setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(XYZTable.COL_ABC)));
        // ... bind cursor data to views
    }

}
```

Comment: Pass in a `LayoutInflater` using `getLayoutInflater()` from your hosting activity, rather than attempting to use `getSystemService()`, and see if that helps.

Comment: Maybe in this case when inflating it should not use parent to set LayoutParams...

Comment: Is your `android:targetSdkVersion` set to 18 or higher? If yes, try temporarily dropping it to 17.

Comment: @CommonsWare no joy with API 17.

Comment: Try this,  public XYZAdapter(YourActivityName context,....) instead of  public XYZAdapter(Context context,...). It works or not, please let me know